# Using fit_generator with multiple inputs gives error at output dense layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

In my case I am using a set of sequential features and also non sequential features to train the model. Following is the architecture of my model

```
Sequential features -> LSTM -> Dense(1) --->>
                                             \
                                              \
                                               -- Dense -> Dense -> Dense(1) ->output
                                              /
                   Non-sequential features---/
```

I am using data generator to generate batches for sequential data. Here the batch size is varying for each batch. For one batch I am keeping the non-sequential feature fixed. Following is my data generator.

```
def training_data_generator(raw_data):
    while True:
        for index, row in raw_data.iterrows():
            x_train, y_train = list(), list()
            feature1 = row['xxx']
            x_current_batch = []
            y_current_batch = []
            for j in range(yyy):
                x_current_batch.append(row['zz1'])
                y_current_batch.append(row['zz2'])
            x_train.append(x_current_batch)
            y_train.append(y_current_batch)
            x_train = array(x_train)
            y_train = array(y_train)

            yield [x_train, np.reshape(feature1,1)], y_train
```

**Note**: x_train y_train sizes are varying.

Following is my model implementation.

```
seq_input = Input(shape=(None, 3))
lstm_layer = LSTM(50)(seq_input)
dense_layer1 = Dense(1)(lstm_layer)

non_seq_input = Input(shape=(1,))

hybrid_model = concatenate([dense_layer1, non_seq_input])

hidden1 = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(hybrid_model)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)

final_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)

model = Model(inputs = [seq_input, non_seq_input], outputs = final_output)

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')

model.fit_generator(training_data_generator(flatten), steps_per_epoch= 5017,
                              epochs = const.NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

I am getting error at the output dense layer

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: 
expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

I think the last layer is getting whole output of the generator but not as one by one.

What is the reason for this issue. Appreciate your insights on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The output gives a Dense layer with a size of 4. Since you've declared your output as a Dense layer with a size of 1, it crashes.

What you can do is change your output dense Layer to 4. And then manually convert this to one value.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: I tried that method. I worked for the first batch. But in the same epoch, for the second batch I got error telling `expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (13,)`. I think the reason is variation of the sized of batches.

Comment: Every batch has to be equally large indeed.

Comment: No, As per my experience, That is not correct. We can have different lengthy batches. I used that with sequential model and it worked fine.

Comment: Are we talking about the rows inside a batch that are different in length, or the batches who are different in length from one another?

Comment: For sequential mode, these are the 2 sets of shapes I am getting from the generator. `x_train - (1,4,3), y_train - (1,4,1)` and  `x_train - (1,13,3), y_train - (1,13,1)`. Are they different sized batches?

Comment: If you use (None, None, 3) for x and (None, None, 1) for y. It will work indeed. But they are different sizes

Comment: Could you please show me where I should change the shapes as you suggested?

Comment: You can just use numpy reshape. For example:               y_train = np.reshape(y_train, shape=(None, None, 1))